# Use numpy to get count of intersecting elements in list of arrays (avoid for loop)

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of values called MyFruits like:

```
[apple, orange, banana, apple, pear]
```

Then I have a list of arrays like:

```
[apple, orange]
[blueberry, watermelon, pear]
[grape, orange, grape, orange]
[]
[cantaloupe]
```

For each of the arrays in the list, I want to get the count of elements that intersect with MyFruits array divided by the total number of elements in the array. So the output would be:

```
2 / 2 = 1
1 / 3 = 0.66667
2 / 4 = 0.5
0 / 0 = (in this case 0)
0 / 1 = 0
```

essentially:

```
[1, 0.66667, 0.5, 0, 0]
```

I've been doing this in Python with for loops, but the data set is huge and it's incredibly slow. Someone suggested using numpy, but I'm having difficulty understanding.

Comment: You show lists of variables (or are those supposed to be strings?).  I don't see arrays.  Show you Python for loops and real data (that we can copy-n-paste).

Comment: If you do this a lot it may be worth while to preprocess the data, converting the lists into an occurrence matrix, a rectangular matrix with one row per list, and one column per 'feature',  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-categorical-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two list, one of length M and another of length N. If done by straightforward linear searches, it would take O(M * N) string comparisons to find which elements are in both lists.

You can improve on that using Python sets. Convert the lists to Python sets and use [set intersection (&)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) to find their common elements. Then the complexity reduces to O(M + N).

Answer (score 0):

Is this any better than what you have, or the same?

```
ratios = []

for d in data:
  count = 0
  for fruit in myFruits:
    count += d.count(fruit)
  ratio = count / (len(d) or 1)
  ratios.append(ratio)
```

Executable in replit: https://repl.it/@ToniAlatalo/CountOccurrences

I don't think numpy can help here, it's for numerical processing, but maybe there is a good way to write what you need otherwise.